# Changed Permissions of /usr/

Tags: permissions, chown

I accidentally ran `sudo chown -R root:root /usr/` on my ubuntu machine (while playing around with sd-card of my Raspberry Pi. I actually wanted to type `sudo chown -R root:root usr/` without slash.)

Now I get this error: `sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`.

Is it possible to fix this?

**EDIT:**
I had the wrong command in my post before. I forgot the `root:root`. Although all files in `/usr` are owned by `root` I get the error message.

Comment: What are you running on the pi?  (ie. OS & release)

Comment: @guiverc There is some misunderstanding. My question is not about a Raspberry Pi. Sorry, if I did not put that right!

Comment: The command `sudo chown -R root:root /usr/` is not the source of your problem, `/usr/bin/sudo` is owned by root anyway and permissions are not changed with this command.

Comment: @mook765 Well, I know, but after running this command the `setuid bit` was not set anymore and don't now why. And some stuff in `/usr/` has different groups then root. I set the `setuid bit` for `sudo` in recovery mode and reinstalled everything and fixed some permissions (`at` `chage` `ssh-agent`) manually.

Comment: @jake Found something interesting here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53665/chown-removes-setuid-bit-bug-or-feature